# Table tablespace shown as X but appears to be 'Users'

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus to create a table with the following sql:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA_OWNER.TEST_TABLE (
  ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  TEST_STRING VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

When I try and do an insert with any user into that table, I see the following error:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, TEST_STRING) values (1, 'Test')
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

This implies that the table has been created in the Users tablespace, but when I look in the USER_TABLES table, I see that the tablespace is the same as all of the other tables, and not 'Users':

```
SELECT table_name, tablespace_name from USER_TABLES;
TABLE_NAME        TABLESPACE_NAME
----------------  ---------------
TABLE1            DATA_TABLESPACE
TEST_TABLE        DATA_TABLESPACE
```

When I create the table in SQL developer using the same SQL, I don't have any errors when inserting data.

1) Why am I getting this error when the table isn't in the Users tablespace?

2) Why am I only getting it when running the sql script from SQL*Plus?

Comment: maybe an index on that table that is on a different tablespace?

Comment: @Aleksej I've actually just come to the same conclusion myself. I think the indexes are being created on a different tablespace. Once I've finished investigating, i'll post an answer.

Comment: @Aleksej Sorted it! thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aleksej for suggesting it could be an issue with the indexes. The problem was that when I was creating the index on the table, I wasn't creating it for the schema owner, which meant that it was being created in a different tablespace.

So instead of

```
CREATE INDEX TEST_TABLE_IDX ON SCHEMA_OWNER.TEST_TABLE(TEST_STRING);
```

I needed to do

```
CREATE INDEX SCHEMA_OWNER.TEST_TABLE_IDX ON SCHEMA_OWNER.TEST_TABLE(TEST_STRING);
```